# How to find the enclosing tags (start and end tag) after searching for a specific keyword in a HTML file?

Tags: html, python-3.x, beautifulsoup

I have a list of keywords which I need to search for in a website. I first extracted the contents of the webpage using BeautifulSoup and stored it in a text file. I wish to search for the list of keywords in the text file (which contains HTML data) and when one of the keywords match, the respective start and end tags where the keyword was found needs to be extracted.
For example-

```
<div class="col-md-6">
<a href="/"><img alt="DC Sustainable Energy Utility: Your Guide to Green" class="img-fluid" src="//d2z33q8cpwfp3p.cloudfront.net/content/dcseu-temp.png"/></a>
</div>
```

I search for the word "Energy" and I find it in the 'img' tag, BUT, I wish to extract the parent tag, which is 'div' here. 
Is there a way I can do that?

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import urllib

#Extracting HTML content from a webpage

webUrl = urllib.request.urlopen("URL")
html_doc = webUrl.read()
soup = BeautifulSoup(html_doc, 'html.parser')
soup = str(soup)
with open('path to .txt file', 'w') as output:
    output.write(soup)

#Extracting start and end tag
from html.parser import HTMLParser

class MyHTMLParser(HTMLParser):
    def handle_starttag(self, tag, attrs):
        print("Encountered a start tag:", tag)

    def handle_endtag(self, tag):
        print("Encountered an end tag :", tag)

    def handle_data(self, data):
        print("Encountered some data  :", data)

parser = MyHTMLParser()
parser.feed('<div class="col-md-6"><a href="/"><img alt="Some Energy Utility: " class="img-fluid" src="//some_image.png"/></a></div>')
```

This identifies all the start and end tags, but I wish to be able to extract the parent/master tags which holds the keyword.

Answer (score 0):

You can find elements with a certain text or `img`s with a certain `alt` text using a custom filter, then find the closest parent of type `div` (or any other criteria `.find_*` methods accept)

```py
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup, Tag

html = '''
<div class="col-md-6">
<a href="/"><img alt="DC Sustainable Energy Utility: Your Guide to Green" class="img-fluid" src="//d2z33q8cpwfp3p.cloudfront.net/content/dcseu-temp.png"/></a>
</div>
'''

keyword = 'energy'

if __name__ == '__main__':
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')


    def keyword_filter(el: Tag):
        """Pick a tag according to its text content"""
        if keyword.lower() in el.text.lower():
            return True
        try:
            if keyword.lower() in el['alt'].lower():
                return True
        except KeyError:
            return False
        return False


    for el in soup.find_all(keyword_filter):
        div = el.find_parent('div')
        print(div)
```